# UITapGestureRecognizer not working when clicking on a DatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using this code to dismiss keyboard when user click's outside the TextField

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   ...
   let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap:")
   view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
   ...
}

func tap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        txtName.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

It is working when the user click's anywhere outside the textfield but the datepicker. When he put's a name and then click on the DatePicker (just click, not roll) the tap is not recognized.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

It's possible the gesture recogniser on the DatePicker is interfering with yours. See if modifying this function helps your case.

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true //Obviously think about the logic of what to return in various cases
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what should I put on the second parameter? Because I didn't add any special gesture recognizer to my DatePicker

Comment: No, but there's going to be multiple GRs active right? There's at least one on the DP and the one you declared on the view controller with the text field in mind.

You should put this override in your code and breakpoint it. Then check out which GRs are running. The results may surprise you.

Comment: I din't get what should i put here .... gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: tapGesture, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: ????????)

Comment: print out what the two GRs are and have a think about what the result should be in each case